# Space between GridLayout items

Tags: android, space, grid-layout

I have a GridLayout in runtime (not a GridView)
This is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    >

 </GridLayout>
```

I add itmes on runtime. The items are a class with Image and Text and everything works good.
I need to have a space between the items (same like a GridView)

How can I do this?

Comment: try margin between them

Comment: You can use "shape" style for your each item and add padding to it in that.

Comment: Shape won't help if you need to add actual spacing. Visually it may be the same, yes, but structurally it's not, right? Margins also won't help when using weight (at least not in appcompat v24 build)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a start

selector_gridview_item_image_blue.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gridview_item_image_border_blue_phone" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_border" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_border"/>

</selector>
```

gridview_item_image_border_blue_phone.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="@color/blue" />

    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="@color/blue" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp" />

</shape>
```